# Phonegap open IPA in Simulator

Tags: iphone, macos, cordova, ipa

I used the phonegap website to create an IPA file.

Now I want to test it in the simulator to make sure it works.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. An IPA file is built to be run on an iOS device only and the simulator can only run Apps built in xCode specifically for the simulator.